# What alternative to capture groups should I use in VimScript?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, search

I understand that Vim does not support regex capture groups. The problem I am trying to solve is being able to easily capture parts of lines.  For example, given the following line of python source code:

```
def is_string(s, *args):
```

I would like to do something equivalent to using the following PCRE regex, which captures the function's name:

```
'^def (\w+) ?\(.*'
```

(the capture group here would match `is_string`

What would be the idiomatic way in VimScript to specify a regex pattern for what part of a line I am trying to match?

Comment: Vim regex supports capture groups, e.g. see http://vimregex.com/#backreferences. Vim supports almost all perl features: https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#perl-patterns.

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that Vim does not support regex capture groups

I'm not sure where you got that idea from. Vim-regex most definitely supports capture groups. It wouldn't be very useful without them...

Your regex is already pretty much right. Just a couple differences with which characters need to be escaped or not:

```
^def \(\w\+\) \?(.*
```

Or if you want to use [very magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623160/can-i-turn-on-extended-regular-expressions-support-in-vim),

```
\v^def (\w+) ?\(.*
```

Comment: s/magic/very magic

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I've realized I didn't ask the right question. I was specifically trying to extract a capture group in VimScript, assigning the contents of a capture group to a variable. After some more digging I found out about the `matchlist()` function which does exactly what I want! Appreciate your time!